# SharePoint 2013 Workflow - How to retrieve the SPWorkflow object associated with a SPListItem?

Tags: 2013, development, workflow, sharepoint-server, tasks

Here's the scenario:

I have a SPListItem in hand, which i know has a started workflow associated. The workflow has a task created for approval.

I want to access the SPWorkflow and then the SPWorkflowTask and update the status of the task via code (Implemented within a web part).

Help please!

**Update 1:**
Tried to access the SPWorkflow object the below mentioned code still no luck. I got an ArgumentOutOfRange exception

```
SPWorkflow changeRequestWorkflow = currentListItem.Workflows[0];
```

**Update 2**

```
manager.GetItemWorkflows(item)
```

this also returned null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I achieved what I wanna do through this => [Implementing custom aspx Workflow Task](http://sp2013.pro/2013/03/creating-spd-2013-workflows-part-23-implementing-custom-asp-net-task-form/#step1). Hope this will be helpful to someone.

**Update 1: How I modified the current task**

Inside the application page that is linked with the new content type. I did the below mentioned when my 'Completed' button was clicked.

```
//Get the SPWorkflow Task item    
var item = SPContext.Current.Item;

item["TaskOutcome"] = "Approved"; //Or Rejected
item["PercentComplete"] = "1";
item["Status"] = "Completed";

item.Update();
```

Try this code and let me know.

Comment: will you be able to share some code how exactly you got the spworkflow and workflow task objects?, I am also stuck in same kind of scenario, unable to find anything of that sort in the mentioned blog

Comment: @user4205 please see my updated answer. I have added the code to update the task.

Answer (score 0):

You can get workflow as:

```
if (item != null && item.Workflows != null && item.Workflows.Count > 0)
{
    try
    {
        var workflows = site.WorkflowManager.GetItemActiveWorkflows(item);
        foreach (SPWorkflow workflow in workflows)
        {
            // match on some indentifiable attribute of your custom workflow
            // the history list title is used below as an example

            if (workflow.ParentAssociation.HistoryListTitle.Equals(Constants.WORKFLOW_HISTORY_LIST_TITLE))
            {
                var workflowTasks = workflow.Tasks;
                if (workflowTasks != null && workflowTasks.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach(SPWorkflowTask task in workflowTasks)
                {
                    //Check if the task is the manager's approval task
                    if (task[task.Fields["Status"].InternalName].ToString() != "Completed")
                    {
                        if (task.Title.Contains("manager"))
                        {
                            taskedit = task;
                            Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
                            ht["Completed"] = "true";
                            ht["Status"] = "Completed";
                            ht["PercentComplete"] = 1.0f;
                            ht["TaskStatus"] = "Approved";

                            SPWorkflowTask.AlterTask((taskedit as SPListItem), ht, true);

                            Console.WriteLine("Task updated");
                        }
                    }  
                }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        // handle error
    }
```

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/58da0dd0-1641-4f26-98d3-6728723825eb/updatecomplete-a-task-outside-of-the-workflow-programmatically?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious

http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Microsoft_Applications/Q_26954974.html

Comment: Im getting an ArgumentOutOfRange exception at 'SPListItem item = leaveApplicationList.Items[46];' Item number 46 exists!

Comment: it starts with index 0. 46 is your last number?

Comment: Got it... It's a count yeah? So I have 3 items in the list. Hence it will be 2. am i correct?

Comment: My taskCollection count is 0. why is that?

Comment: please see my update.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/malag/archive/2009/05/20/how-to-programmatically-complete-approval-workflow-task.aspx

Comment: SPWorkflowTask task = item.Tasks[0]; is returning null for me because the item.Tasks collection is empty. But I have a task for this list item.

Comment: Still stuck... Tried using the SPWorkflowManager. Dint help either.

Comment: what kind of workflows are you using?

Comment: SharePoint 2013 Workflow developed in Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13232420/splistitem-tasks-always-empty This would help you.

Comment: This line => item.Workflows.Count > 0 is always false for me... Why is that?

Comment: found this - http://sp2013.pro/2013/03/creating-spd-2013-workflows-part-23-implementing-custom-asp-net-task-form/#step1 It helped me to get what I want :)! Thanks